# Javascript if statement will not execute MVC3/razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('@(Model.DidPass)' == 'True') {
        alert('Blah Blah True');
    }
    else {
        alert('Blah blah false');
    }
</script>
```

in Fiddler I can see that my if statements renders in the browser as:

```
if ('True' == 'True')
```

yet for some reason the alert('Blah blah blah True') will not execute. If I step through the code in VS I can watch it get as far as the if statement then just bug out.
Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe a video of me stepping through my code?
I promise. It hits the if statement, but doesn't run either alerts.

Comment: A screen shot would be awesome, yes

Comment: I think my problem goes way deeper than this. Because it doesn't make sense that it wouldn't work. I think the partial view I'm returning that this code is in is somehow not getting rendered.

Comment: Ya, my view wasn't getting rendered properly. The above code works.

Answer (score 7):

Your going to need to transition from code to html like so. Otherwise the compiler will assume that `alert` is a c# method call (which it isn't) and you'll get a compiler error when you attempt to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if(Model.DidPass){
        @:alert('Blah Blah True');
    } else {
        @:alert('Blah blah false');
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively you can use the psuedo element `<text></text>` if your javascript takes up more than one line. The `@:` is only for the text following all the way until a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
    if (Boolean('@(Model.DidPass)') == true) {
        alert('Blah Blah True');
    }
    else {
        alert('Blah blah false');
    }
```

Comment: I down voted because of the unnecessary complexity, awkward syntax, etc.

Comment: 1st it's not awkward, 2nd it's valid JavaScript, and 3rd it's only for testing purposes. Hence 'Did you try'. Try as in Make an attempt or effort to do something.

Comment: 1, It looks awkward to me but I do regret downvoting for it. 2, I understand that it's valid javascript, and my dislike of it is largely in part to having dynamic javascript, not your code (sorry). 3, understood.. again, I wish I could roll back a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Eh.. that's not how i'd do it but, since you are going to do it that way why don't you just do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('@(Model.DidPass ? "blahblahblah true" : "blahlbahlbah false")');
</script>
```

*edit :* fixed code by rolling it back to a ternary..

Comment: I had it like that originally, edited it a lot because I was trying to get it to work. It won't hit either of the alerts no matter how I do it.

Comment: Then there is a problem with your javascript somewhere else. Use firebug in Firefox to see what kind of error it gives you.

Comment: @Chance, your code won't compile. See [BuildStarted's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759805/javascript-if-statement-will-not-execute-mvc3-razor/7759964#7759964) to understand why or try it yourself. There is no such function in C# called `alert`.

Comment: @Darin geh, I forgot to wrap in quotes. It's been awhile since I touched razor :/

Comment: @Chance, what quotes? You should use `@:` or wrap in `<text>` node.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i had originally planned to make it a ternary but changed it at the last minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try === instead maybe?

Never used this MVC3/razor stuff ( or even know what it is ), so this is just a guess